# Status thermal printer with libusb on linux ARM

Tags: c++, qt, usb, thermal-printer, libusb-1.0

I known there is a lot of question about status printer ...

i have a Citizen CT-S310 II, i have managed all the code for write character in USB without problem with libusb_bulk_transfer (Text, Bold, Center, CR, CUT_PAPER etc) :

```
#define ENDPOINT_OUT    0x02
#define ENDPOINT_IN     0x81

struct libusb_device_handle *_handle;

[detach kernel driver...]
[claim interface...]
[etc ...]

r = libusb_bulk_transfer(device_handle, ENDPOINT_OUT, Mydata, out_len, &transferred, 1000);
```

Now, i need to receive data from the printer to ckeck the status, my first idea was to send the POS command with the same "bulk_transfer" of the doc :

1D (hexa) 72 (hexa) n
n => 1 (Send the papel sensor status)

and retrieve the value by "bulk_transfer" with the end point "ENDPOINT_IN" the doc say there is 8 bytes to receive :

```
bit 0,1 => paper found by paper near-end sensor 00H
bit 0,1 => paper not found by paper near-end sensor 03H
bit 1,2 => paper found by paper-end sensor 00H
bit 1,2 => paper not found by paper-end sensor 0CH
[...]
```

so two "bulk_transfer", one for send command status (ENDPOINT_OUT) and one for receive the result (ENDPOINT_IN), but i have allways an USB ERROR ("bulk_transfer" in read = -1)

Maybe the USB don't work like this ? So my second idea was to use the implemented function in PrinterClass USB with the command "control_transfer" :

```
int r = 0;
    int out_len = 1;
    unsigned char* _udata = NULL;

    uint8_t bmRequestType = LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE;
    uint8_t bRequest = LIBUSB_REQUEST_GET_STATUS;
    uint16_t wValue = 0; // the value field for the setup packet (?????)
    uint16_t wIndex = 0; // N° interface printer (the index field for the setup packet)

    r = libusb_control_transfer(device_handle, bmRequestType,bRequest,wValue, wIndex,_udata,out_len, USB_TIMEOUT);
```

i don't exactly how to fill all the parameter, i know it depend of my device, but the doc of libsub is not very explicit.

What is exactly "wValue" ?

What is exactly "wIndex" ? the interface number ??

the parameter LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN by default is 0x80, but my printer use 0x81, i must to change this default endpoint ?

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1d90:2060
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d90
  idProduct          0x2060
  bcdDevice            0.02
  iManufacturer           1 CITIZEN
  iProduct                2 Thermal Printer
  iSerial                 3 00000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

The response of "control_transfer" in my case is always 0 :( with paper or without.How send a good "control_transfer" for request the status of my printer ??

All the help for solve my problem is welcome !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally resolved !

The value of LIBUSB_REQUEST_GET_STATUS is 0x00, but for a printer the request status is 0x01.

for check the status of printer with libusb-1.0 :

```
uint8_t bmRequestType = LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE;
    uint8_t bRequest = 0x01; // Here not LIBUSB_REQUEST_GET_STATUS
    uint16_t wValue = 0;
    uint16_t wIndex = 0;

    r = libusb_control_transfer(device_handle, bmRequestType,bRequest,wValue, wIndex,&_udata,out_len, USB_TIMEOUT);
```